See Android notifications in Ubuntu MATE
I'm using Ubuntu MATE 24.04. I need to be aware when my Android device notifies me about new messages, calls, WhatsApp, and everything else when I'm not looking at my mobile device screen. It happens many times in a day that I need to go and check it manually. While I'm looking at my PC's screen, I may miss many of them. The office policy is to silence mobile devices. I may be in meetings, etc. anything may cause me to get involved with many other things and don't remember to check my notifications.
It may be a very good solution if I have something on my PC's screen to communicate with the mobile and show me that I have new notifications, e.g. an icon in the notification area may get red/green or something. My mobile device uses data for communicating with the internet and we've no WiFi at the office. LAN is completely in another network.
Is there any possibility of this?

Maybe look into using KDE Connect.
https://kdeconnect.kde.org/
sudo apt install kdeconnect

From the page above:  "KDE Connect is available on all major distributions and works on all desktop environments."
To connect outside of the network look into the following:
https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#Running_KDE_Connect_over_OpenVPN
Maybe others here might have a better solution, but from my experience this one worked for me.

But the DE is MATE

Besides, KDE Connect needs both PC and the device be on the same network.

Thank you, I will check it.

I read the link. Thanks, but unfortunately it's out of my expertise. Isn't there a simpler solution?

@hamidi This answer explains an alternative way of doing it for Ubuntu desktop environment, however it still isn't MATE desktop environment so take your pick and keep the one you like better.

Thank you. I'll try my best. :)
